# Remove all dates prior to specific date in all years

Tags: r, date, dataframe

How to remove all dates prior to a specific date, say, 15th of March?

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("1990/1/1"), as.Date("1999/1/1"), "days")
```

I would need to subset a data frame based on this vector.

Comment: Is it between 1st of January to 15th March

Comment: after, but I guess it doesn't matter...

Comment: @akrun don't think that comment's quite right---it will keep Jan 14 but drop Jan 16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `lubridate` for readability:

```
library(lubridate)
dates[month(dates) > 3 | (month(dates) == 3 & day(dates) >= 15)]
```

Base version  of the same logic:

```
dates[as.integer(format(dates, "%m")) > 3 |
    (as.integer(format(dates, "%m")) == 3 & as.integer(format(dates, "%d")) >= 15)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding up Gregor's answer, but using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

filtered_df = df %>% filter((month(dates) == 3 & days(dates) >= 15) | month(dates) > 3)
```